# $scope.$digest() with setTimeout best practices

Tags: angularjs

Can someone confirm if my syntax using $digest() is good ?

```
        $scope.onchangeCheckbox = function() {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                    $scope.filterItems();
                    $scope.scrollCollectionTop(); 
                    $scope.$digest();
            },500);
        }
```

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Please use `$timeout`. This will automatically call `$digest`.

```
$scope.onchangeCheckbox = function() {
            $timeout(function(){ 
                    $scope.filterItems();
                    $scope.scrollCollectionTop(); 
                    //$scope.$digest();
            },500);
        }
```

This is the real angular way.

Comment: thanks. But I though that $timeout was calling $apply() and not $digest(). I only need to refresh the current scope.

Comment: Both these functions are in a single process chain. Your changes are applied to the scope.

Comment: I mean that I don't need to refresh the $rootscope, but jsut the current scope, and I think that $timeout uses $apply() so it refreshes all the scopes, isn't it right ?

Comment: $scope.$apply() takes a function or an Angular expression string, and executes it, then calls $scope.$digest() to update any bindings or watchers. All these happen in $scope - I think. You can easily run a test.